# The roots of $J' = \frac{dJ}{d\tau}$

Tags: elliptic-curves, modular-forms, elliptic-functions, modular-function

I was wondering if anything is known about the roots of $J' = \frac{dJ}{d\tau}$. Here, $J(\tau) = j(\tau)/12^3$ is Klein's absolute invariant. Some roots can be calculated (at least I know how to), but is anything general known?

Comment: Using [Ramanujan's system of ODEs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein_series#Ramanujan_identities), you can express $\frac{1}{2\pi\mathrm{i}}\frac{\mathrm{d}j}{\mathrm{d}\tau}$ as a rational function of Eisenstein series; the denominator is the modular discriminant, and the numerator holds the answer to your question.

Comment: The solution here is much easier than the one to [that question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1701711).

Comment: @ccorn Using Ramanujan's differential equations we get $J'/J = -2\pi i E_6(\tau)/E_4(\tau)$. Are the roots of $E_6(\tau)$ known? Do they all have explicit form or are they all in a certain region? Is anything general known?

Comment: @ccorn I came across a theorem of Rankin and Swinnerton-Dyer, which was interesting.

Comment: Correct so far; multiply with the expression of $J$ in terms of Eisenstein series to get the full numerator relevant for $J'$. As for the zeros of $E_4$ and $E_6$, this has been covered (indirectly) e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/587201) and [there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1469939). I suppose you can then present the answer yourself, I am looking forward to that.